# Python function for multiplication of arrays by index

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: If the second is nx1, simple `a*b` works

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked numpy library? it makes working with matrices a lot easier. You can check it out in this links: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_data_structure/python_matrix.htm

numpy gives you a .dot method for matrix multiplication. Hope this guides you enough --> https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html#numpy.dot

Comment: this is not ana answer and would be  in better place in the comments of the question.

Comment: I need at least 50 reputation for adding comments ( wich i dont have). I thought it could help him/her... Sorry if i was wrong

Comment: I don't think he wants matrix multiplication.  He wants element by element multiplication, without any summing.  A (m,n) can @ with a (n,1) producing a (m,1), but I think he wants a (m,n).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a matrix like

```
mat=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],
[2,3,4,5,6],
[3,4,5,6,7]])
```

and an array like

```
arr=np.array([1,2,3])
```

Then the required function using numpy multiplication can be so simple:

```
def multiplicate(mat,arr):
    mat*arr.reshape((3,1))
```